# What is a kilbis fish?

Tags: words, talmud-gemara, translation, fish, masecheth-avodah-zarah

The Gemara (Avodah Zarah 40a) mentions that if you find a "kilbis" (כילבית) fish in fish brine you can eat it. What does a "kilbis" fish translate out to in English?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ephraim and thanks for this first question. 

Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!

Comment: From my understanding of the context in which this word is used at the bottom of the previous page, I don't think this is a type of fish, but rather a characteristic or feature that is found in a fish that distinguishes it from being a kosher fish or not. See the last Rash"i at the bottom of p. 39b. I'll see if I can run the words by a (human) translator.

Answer (score 6):

Jastrow suggests that the kilbith fish may be a [stickleback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stickleback).

> כִּלְ' , (כִּילְבִּית) כִּילְכִּית f. (=כילכלית, v. כלכל; or denom. of כלב, emp. כּוּלָב) name of a *small fish*, supposed to be a *stickleback*.

<sup>*Dictionary of Targumim, Talmud and Midrashic Literature*  by Marcus Jastrow, 1926</sup>

Additionally, the [Soncino Talmud](https://halakhah.com/tcontents.html) to Avodah Zarah 35b ([footnote 18](https://halakhah.com/zarah/zarah_35.html#35b_18)), suggests a stickleback also:

> The kalbith was a kind of stickleback which was supposed to breed only in brine formed with the clean species of fish.

<sup>Thank you, [Tamir Evan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1368/tamir-evan), for finding this.</sup>

It seems that the kilbith's *exact* identity is uncertain.